Texcount: how to count superscript in text citation correctly?

Using \usepackage[super,numbers]{natbib} in the preamble makes in
text citation to be superscript
Having %TC:macro \cite [option:text,text] additionally makes
texcount include in text citations as part of the

word count.
Now:

"life\cite{RN3375}" counts as two words, but how would I make it
count as one word?
"life\cite{RN3375, RN3374, RN3376}" counts as 4 words, but I need it
to count as 3 words

Essentially how can I make it count in text citation such that the first citation that is sticking to a word doesn't get counted as an additional word?

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[super,numbers]{natbib}


\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -q -relaxed -sum=1,1,0,0,0,1,1  -merge #1.tex output.bbl > #1-words.sum }%
  % \verbatiminput{#1-words.sum}%
  \input{#1-words.sum}%
}\begin{document}
%TC:macro \cite [option:text,text]


word\cite{TM83}

word\cite{GMP81, TM83}
%TC:ignore

Word count: \protect\quickwordcount{main}words
% To change the title from References to Bibliography:
\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % or try abbrvnat or unsrtnat
\bibliography{example} % refers to example.bib
%TC:endignore

\end{document}


I can't come up with a solution that does exactly what you want, but there is an alternative approach.
You can count the number of calls to \cite, and subtract it from the number of words counted. Here's an example which also counts the number of citations within \cite separately:
%TC:newcounter cite Number of citations
%TC:newcounter ncite Number of calls to cite
%TC:macro \cite [option:text,cite]
%TC:macroword \cite [ncite]

Once you have the number of words, you can then add cite and subtract ncite to get the count you want.
I thought of trying to specify a negative count of \cite, but it does not allow for negative values: that should be an easy fix, I think, but would require modifying the script. The -sum option did not allow for negative values either, and could not incorporate the new counters.
However, it is possible to customise the output by specifying an output template:
%TC:newtemplate
%TC:template Count: {word}+{headerword}+{otherword}+{inline}+{displaymath}+{cite}-{ncite}\n
%TC:template Sum: {word+headerword+otherword+inline+displaymath+cite-ncite}\n

In the templates, linear combinations of the counters can be used, including with negative weights. Note that newlines have to be specified using \n.

I don't know why, but when I put a newcounter in, and add extra numbers for the sum=, I get the error in stderr that it is an invalid option, in the perl code it looks like it's hard coded to only accept 7 digits for the sum option?
I'm not sure how you would incorporate -1 into the perl code, but I also can think of counting sum=1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0, then minusing sum=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1

@StevenZhang: You're right. The -sum options does not support additional counters. There is a template option which I'm pretty sure can be used. I'll try work it out and post it later: hopefully tonight.

did you have any luck with finding a solution using the template option?

@StevenZhang: The answer has been updated with a solution.
